# How do you set the font size of a Chart Title with Python PPTX?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I add a chart with:

```
doughnutchart_data.add_series('YTD COMPLETION TO PLAN', (PerformancePercent, NotPerformedPercent))
```

This gives me a chart title with the text, but how do I change the font size?
This:

```
ThisDoughnutChart.title.font.size = Pt(12)
```

Gives me this error:
AttributeError: 'Chart' object has no attribute 'title'

Answer (score 11):

It seems that creating a chart title text_frame over writes the title applied from the add_series attribute. So I tried adding a new title. This worked for me:

```
 ThisDoughnutChart.chart_title.text_frame.text = 'YTD COMPLETION TO PLAN'
 ThisDoughnutChart.chart_title.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size = Pt(12)
```

Answer (score 3):

Version 0.6.11 another example

```
shape = slide.shapes
title_shape = shape.title
title_shape.text_frame.paragraphs[0].font.size=Pt(10)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the global font size of the chart with the following:

```
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt

ThisDoughnutChart.font.size = Pt(10)
```